# Powershell variable not being populated

Tags: powershell

Here's the simple script:

```
$groups = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $server | Select-object @{N="Group";E={($_.PartComponent -split "Name=")[1].Replace('"','')}}
$groups
```

However, `$groups` is `null`!

I've checked the interwebs and cannot find a solution.

I'm sure there's a simple answer...

Comment: What is your code supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Query is syntactically correct. Check if you are storing the correct value in the `$server` parameter and that your **WMI service** is running.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with what you have here, as it pulls the data when I test this. 
Note I am using my localhost, not a remote system here.

```
(
$groups = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME `
| Select-object @{N="Group";E={($_.PartComponent -split "Name=")[1].Replace('"','')}}
)

Group              
-----              
postanote
...             
IUSR               
...            
SYSTEM             
...          
INTERACTIVE        
Authenticated Users
...           
DefaultAccount     
Guest              
Administrator      
...             
SYSTEM             
...   

$groups.Count   

27
```

And fine on a remote system.

```
(
$groups = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName 'ws01' `
| Select-object @{N="Group";E={($_.PartComponent -split "Name=")[1].Replace('"','')}}
)

Group                    
-----                    
Administrator            
Domain Admins            
...               
Guest                    
SYSTEM                   
...                
INTERACTIVE              
Authenticated Users      
Domain Users             
SYSTEM 

$groups.Count 

18
```

So, something environmental in your environment, is the catch 22 for you.

Run this on your localhost host and see if you can get anything back from your targets.

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName ws01

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```